# Symfony generatUrl problem .... must match "[^/]++" ("my string with special chars" given) to generate a corresponding URL."

Tags: php, symfony, encoding, routes

I am trying to use the google indexer api with symfony and therefore i need to generate the same URLs dynamically from my job-entity (in the database) like i am already using in the frontend.

My controller function looks (reduced) like this

```
/**
 *
 * @Route({
 *     "de": "/profile/{name}-{id}/career/{jobname}-{jobid}",
 *     },  name="somename")
 */
public function detailfunction($name, $id, $jobname, $jobid)
{ // some code
}
```

In my frontend i get the following url rendered by twig (path function):

https://www.mydomain.xy/profile/This+is+a+company+name-23/career/Worker+Montage+%2528mwd%2529-135

So now i need to send the exact same url to google so it updates the index whenever this page is modified.

I try to generate this url in the controller of my "google indexer" function like this:

```
$job = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Jobs::class)->findBy(....);
$url = $this->generateUrl('somename', array('name' => $job->getCompany()->getName(),
                                            'id' => $job->getCompany()->getid(),
                                            'jobname" => $job->getTitle(),
                                            'jobid' => $job->getId()));

// Debug
echo $url;
```

Unfortunately it outputs "ERROR : Parameter "jobname" for route "somename" must match "[^/]++" ("Worker Montage (m/w/d)" given) to generate a corresponding URL"

So it doesn´t encode the data that comes from the database for the url generator. I have been wondering how symfony (or twig as well) actually encodes internally but i am completely lost and very thankful for a hint.

Comment: It is the slashes within `(m/w/d)` from `$job->getTitle()` causing it. When generating the titles, maybe you can change the format? `eg. Worker Montage (mwd) or Worker Montage (m\w\d)`.

Comment: Looks like the Twig bridge does this, double decoding your URL gives `https://www.mydomain.xy/profile/This is a company name-23/career/Worker Montage (mwd)-135`

Comment: Thank your for your reply @bossman but this does not explain my question. I am using the same Jobtitle (with the (m/w/d)) when i am using the twig function and it works perfectly (see the frontend link above). I know that it´s the special characters causing it but i have no idea why it´s working in twig but when i try to use the same logic in a controller, i causes an error.

Comment: Not sure why that is working for you. Using `path('example', {'name': 'testing (w/m/d)', 'id': 99})` throws the same error. [Here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php) is the source for `path` in the Symfony Twig Bridge. It uses the `UrlGeneratorInterface` the same as the controller does. It does however run it through a callback function that does extra escaping, it may be of interest to you..

Answer (score 0):

Although i am still not sure of how exactly symfony / twig encodes the url, i wrote a small workaround function and call it before passing it to the generateURL function.

```
  array('name' => $this->urlcleaner($job->getCompany()->getName()),
        'id' => $job->getCompany()->getId(),



private function urlcleaner($string){

    $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-ığşçöüÖÇŞİıĞ()\/]/', ' ', $string);
    $string = str_replace("/","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("-","",$string);
    $string = urlencode($string);

    return $string;
}
```